# Coldfusion websocket security error

Tags: websocket, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm using the example found [Here](http://www.sagarganatra.com/2012/03/html5-websockets-in-coldfusion-10.html) and received the following error:

> Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.

Is there some configuration I missed or something?

The full code is linked to on the page, but the line with the error is:

```
<cfwebsocket name="socket"
             onMessage ="messageHandler"
             onOpen = "openHandler"
             onClose = "closeHandler">
```

Looking into this further, cfwebsocket has a property as of coldfusion 11, secure, with which the web socket communication will happen over SSL. Is there something in 10 I can use to do this?

Comment: Do you have any code associated with this?